# Wrap calls to NSLog in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nslog, variadic-functions

I want to be able to wrap all calls to NSLog in my Class so I can have a single place to enable/disable logging.

I can't figure out how to accept variable numbers of arguments to my method and then hand them on to NSLog.

Examples, please.

Comment: Erm, http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html ? However, if you want slightly more sophistication in your logging, check out https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack .

Comment: Generally this is done by writing a new macro that includes the appropriate enable/disable logic, and using that macro in place of NSLog.  There are probably a dozen examples here if you look, and likely hundreds elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for a logger I'd just go with a macro

```
#if DEBUG
#warning LOGGING ENABLED
#define DebugLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#else
#define DebugLog(...)

#endif
```

#### BUT

if you want to work with variable arguments:

declare your method as so it takes a variable number of arguments

`+ (id)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...;`

use the va_* C functions to interact with the variable arguments

- va_start - Initializes a va_list
- va_arg - Fetches the next argument out of the list.
- va_end - Releases any memory by the list of vas

---

DEMO for the logging

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#define DEBUG 1

#if DEBUG
#warning LOGGING ENABLED
#define DebugLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#else
#define DebugLog(...)

#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
                    id v = @1;
        DebugLog(@"bla: %@", v);        
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this working successfully, but when in RELEASE mode I get lots of Unused Entity Issue warnings for the various variables I'm now not using in logging. Can I turn those off, or do people not tend to worry about it?

Comment: Because the DebugLog(...) in the else block is incorrect. it needs to have `do { } while (0)` after it. See my answer for how DLog is turned off in Release.

Comment: no. the macro is fine. sorry abizern

Comment: I'm not saying it's entirely wrong, just that the implementation of that small part needs the do-nothing implementation to silence the compiler warning.

Answer (score 2):

I use a handy set of Macros from [Marcus Zarra](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/05/02/my-current-prefix-pch-file/):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  #define DLog(...) NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
  #define ALog(...) [[NSAssertionHandler currentHandler] handleFailureInFunction:[NSString stringWithCString:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] file:[NSString stringWithCString:__FILE__ encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] lineNumber:__LINE__ description:__VA_ARGS__]
#else
  #define DLog(...) do { } while (0)
  #ifndef NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
    #define NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS
  #endif
  #define ALog(...) NSLog(@"%s %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [NSString stringWithFormat:__VA_ARGS__])
#endif

#define ZAssert(condition, ...) do { if (!(condition)) { ALog(__VA_ARGS__); }} while(0)
```

This doesn't need any configuration as DEBUG and RELEASE are defined by Xcode as standard. This provides:

- DLog() Only emits an NSLog in DEBUG
- ALog() Throws an assertion with the message in DEBUG, and emits an NSLog in RELEASE
- ZAssert() Throws an Assertion if the condition fails in DEBUG, and emits an NSLog if the condition fails in RELEASE.

And the logs are pretty printed - showing the class and method where the log is emitted.

Comment: just copies above.. + mine isn't wrong. I use it in X apps and I just tested it again :D

Comment: Really? I've been using this for about 4 years now as you can see from https://gist.github.com/Abizern/325926. A retaliatory -1? Classy.

Comment: I revoked my vote ;) but I really disliked your comment that just said 'it is incorrect' .. no reason whatsoever

Comment: I dont wanna say it cant be wrong but I don't see any reason. Please shed some light incase of just saying ;wrong;

Comment: That was a reply to the comment above, about silencing the compiler warnings. I'm not saying your entire method is not correct, just that the warnings can be silenced by providing a do-nothing implementation.